# Terminal adds too much whitespace when there are surrogate-pair emoji in the prompt

Tags: terminal, zsh

I've set my prompt using this:

```
PROMPT='‍ %1d: '
```

but now terminal puts the cursor quite far behind the colon. When I type text, the text does appear where I'd expect it to, but the cursor shows up much further along the lined.

This seems to happen because the terminal doesn't understand characters that are part of a surrogate pair. If I use something like the emoji instead, it works as expected.

Comment: Zsh is the problem, not Terminal.

Comment: So is there a way I can configure zsh to handle these correctly?

Comment: I have no use for zsh, but it, like other shells, should have the ability to be configured to deal with non-printing and multibyte characters in its prompt.

Comment: I see the effect you describe in Terminal, but it works just fine in iTerm2. (Cc @MarcWilson: both the shell and the terminal matter.) I thought that `PROMPT='%2{‍%} %1d: '` would do the trick, but no, it doesn't help. I'm not sure it's possible to work around this Terminal limitation.